# Does Redis hash guarantee that no two different keys have same hash?

Tags: hash, redis

Does Redis hash mentioned at https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-3-commands-in-redis/3-4-hashes/, guarantee that two different Strings will have two different hash?If not, then how collisions are handled.I cannot find any such information on web.

Use Case :- I want to store my suggestion index into redis. For every word, i want to give some suggestions

```
{
"hel":"hell,hello"
"cap" : "captain,capital"
}
```

and so on.

So if i use this info in redis hash as a key value.Is it guaranteed that no two keys will have same hash? So that when i am looking up hash table, i should not show something irrelevant.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You assign the name of the hashes yourself, so if you use the same one twice you'll overwrite the contents the second time.

Comment: update question with use case

Comment: Hash tables (in any language or db) don't have to generate unique values to work. To quote the Wikipedia page "most hash table designs employ an imperfect hash function, which might cause hash collisions where the hash function generates the same index for more than one key. Such collisions are typically accommodated in some way."

Comment: so that means i cannot use redis hash set right ?Then i am wondering what can be perfect use case of redis hash set?Because anyhow even if our keys are generated unique but redis hash may generate same hash which can mess things up.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If the key is unique, you will be able to retrieve the value. You don't need to worry about what Redis does with hash-underneath.

Comment: I was  thinking like , let us say I have two keys namely " Foo", "bar" and these both are having different list of suggestions. In real world it is possible that "Foo" and "Bar" got same hash key when redis applied its hash function and then only one of them will be stored in redis.Is it possible?

Comment: It's not possible. I don't know the specifics of how Redis deals with it, but for instance Java Hashmap uses the hashing function to decide which "bucket" to store the key and value in. Ideally the hashing function would generate a unique value, for performance reasons, so there's only one to key/value to retrieve from the "bucket", but if there's more than one it can go through them until it finds the one with the correct key. Ultimately if you can store something by its key, you can retrieve it by its key. Don't worry about what the hashing does.

Comment: yeah cool.it makes sense